# Reverse order of RSS feed in zRSSfeed (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, rss, jfeed

Im using zRSSfeed and everything is great but I need to be able to reverse the order of the feed, does anybody know how to do it?

The zRSSfeed uses jQuery to pull the feed so anything applicable to that should apply as well.

Any ideas? I dont want to use Yahoo Pipes as there is a delay issue.

Comment: Can you show us some markup that is generated by the feed ?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version allows you to sort by date or title in ascending or descending order.

For example:

```
$('#test').rssfeed('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews', {
    sort: 'title',
    sortasc: true
});
```

http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed